# drupal - which modules for teachers and students in school

Tags: drupal-6, organic-groups

I want to do something with drupal 6. Here the project
 Each teacher manages a class composed of several groups. Teachers only have access to their own groups. By connecting each teacher is directed to a page (or dashboard homebox) containing: its student groups with each group their latest posts, a link to their blogs (blog group), a place to send (create) a post (blog entry) to all groups or a specific group. Each group of students connect with the user name and password of the administrator of the group (one group member has the right to connect) and are directed to a page that contains: All posts sent by the group, members of the group, a place to send (create) a post (blog entry) only to the teacher, and a page explaining the course.
 How much do I create roles (teachers and students only?)
 which modules should I use? og, og_menu, og-audience ... or I have seen recement school administration Drupal 7 is ok?

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to use [moodle](http://moodle.org/) .. its greet in this task...

then you can integrate it with drupal... there is alot of module that support this integration ...

and i think [QUIZ](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) module for drupal is very helpful for you

**UPDATE:**

Drupal 6 have a set of [modules](http://drupal.org/project/moodle) that help you integrating your moodle with drupal

but unfortunately DRUPAL 7  still not supported

goodluck

Comment: i want to use drupal. is possible to integrate moodle in drupal ?